# What is nbinom.rvs returning?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I'm trying to understand what scipy.stats.nbinom.rvs is returning. Here is a sample of code:

*Code:**

```
from scipy.stats import nbinom
for i in range(10):
    x = nbinom.rvs(n = 20, p = 0.5, size = 1)
    print(str(i) + ": " + str(x[0]))
```

I thought this was basically saying: How many trials did it take to find 20 successes when flipping a coin (p=0.5). But a sample of my output shows some returns are well below 20. And since its impossible to get 20 success in 8 flips, I clearly don't understand the return value. Help please.

**Sample output:**

```
0: 19
1: 25
2: 14
3: 24
4: 30
5: 8
6: 28
7: 21
8: 14
9: 30
```

I've looked at the docs online but just seeing "random variates" isn't very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docstring of `scipy.stats.nbinom`:

```
The probability mass function of the number of failures for `nbinom` is:

.. math::

   f(k) = \binom{k+n-1}{n-1} p^n (1-p)^k

for :math:`k \ge 0`.

`nbinom` takes :math:`n` and :math:`p` as shape parameters where n is the
number of successes, whereas p is the probability of a single success.
```

So the values that you see are the number of "failures" that occur before achieving `n` "successes".

There is a note on the [wikipedia page for the negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) that is worth repeating here:

> Different texts adopt slightly different definitions for the negative binomial distribution. They can be distinguished by whether the support starts at k = 0 or at k = r, whether p denotes the probability of a success or of a failure, and whether r represents success or failure, so it is crucial to identify the specific parametrization used in any given text.